# Open and attach file to mailer from database string

Tags: php, sql-server, phpmailer

So I am working on a project where I have a file that has been stored in a database with the fields of name, data, and mime-type. It is not under my control why the file is stored like that, it just is.

Next, I have a system where there is an approve or deny setting. If approved I have to take that file from the database and attach it to a mailer and send it. I can get the mailer to send but it never has the attachment with it. So I need to figure out what I am doing wrong and how to get the file to attach.

For simplicity I am using PHPMailer, and my database is SQL Server 2012. My code is also very lengthy, so I placed only the needed part below. if there is more information you require, please ask! Thank you for all help in advance.

**PHP**

```
try{    
    $mail = $MAIL;
    $decision = $approve == 1 ? "<span style='color:#00dd00;'><b>Approved</b></span>" : "<span style='color:#dd0000;'><b>Denied</b></span>";
    $complete_time = date('m/d/Y');
    $name = explode(" ", LDAPGetName($underwriter, $LDAP));
    $name = $name[0];
    $to = LDAPGetEmail($underwriter, $LDAP);
    $mail->setFrom('no-reply@example.com');
    $mail->addAddress($to);
    if($approve == 1){
        $q = "SELECT file_data, file_name, file_type FROM doc_file WHERE doc__id ='$id'";
        $file_data = "";
        $file_name = "";
        $file_type = "";
        foreach($CONN->query($q) as $row){
            $file_data = $row['file_data'];
            $file_name = $row['file_name'];
            $file_type = $row['file_type'];
        }
        $file = hextobin($file_data);
        $mail->AddAttachment($file);
    }
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = "Lease Application Update for Lease #$lease";
    $message = "<html>";
        $message .= "<body>";
            $message .= "<h2>Lease Application Update</h2>";
            $message .= "<hr />";
            $message .= "<p>Hello $name,</p>";
            $message .= "<p>This message is to inform you that there has been a decision made on application for
            lease number $lease. Please see below for details.</p>";
            $message .= "<table rules='all' style='border-color: #666; cellpadding='10'>";
                $message .= "<tr><td>Lease #:</td><td>$lease</td></tr>";
                $message .= "<tr><td>Date:</td><td>$complete_time</td></tr>";
                $message .= "<tr><td>Completed By:</td><td>$USER</td></tr>";
                $message .= "<tr><td>Decision:</td><td>$decision</td></tr>";
                $message .= "<tr><td colspan='2'><center><b>Decision Notes</b></center></td></tr>";
                $message .= "<tr><td colspan='2'>$notes</td></tr>";
            $message .= "</table>";
        $message .= "</body>";
    $message .= "</html>";
    $mail->Body = $message;
    $mail->send();
    $response['errors'] = false;
    $response['success_message'] = "Lease application successfully updated and all necessary parties notified";
}catch(phpmailerException $e){
    $response['errors'] = true;
    $response['error_message'] = "The lease application status has been updated however there was an error when trying to send a message to the saleperson: <br>".$e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: addattachment expects a file. phpmailer does have a semi-undocumented attachfromstring()-type method, though I'm pulling a senior moment remember exactly what the method's name is. worxware really needs to step up and fix their documentation for the whole library.

Comment: I agree, it was a pain just to figure out how to do error handling

Comment: see linked dupe. it shows exactly what you need.